# cannot remove the last element of a python list

Tags: python, list

I just simply want to remove all the elements in the python list one by one by `remove()` method, but find out that does not work. I run the code below:

```
a=[1,2,3]
for i in a:
    a.remove(i)
print a
```

and it shows

```
[2]
```

Comment: It's a [common pitfall](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/949/changing-the-sequence-you-are-iterating-over#t=201608202137582428236)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening there is that you are changing a list while you iterate over it, but the iterator on that list will not get updated with your changes. So as you delete the first element (`index = 0`) in the first iteration, the second one (`index = 1`) becomes now the first (`index = 0`), but the iterator will next return the second (`index = 1`) element instead of returning (again) the first one that has changed and has been skipped. Step by step:

1. Iterator starts at index 0, which is element `1`. List is `[1, 2, 3]`. You remove that element and end up with `[2, 3]`.
2. Iterator moves to index 1, which is element `3` (note 2 has been skipped). You remove that element and end up with `[2]`.
3. Iterator moves to index 2, which doesn't exist, so iteration is over.

Comment: Thank you very much Danziger !!!

Comment: what is the alternative solution ?