# Why doesn't the remove method correctly remove all occurences of an element in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am given an array and a value. I have to remove all occurences of the value in the given array.

The code I wrote is not working especially for this test case.

- **array=[0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]**
- **value=2**

**My code:**

```
def removeElement(nums, val):
        for i in nums:
            if i==val:
                nums.remove(i)
        return nums
```

Expected output: `[0,1,3,0,4]`
My output: `[0,1,3,0,4,2]`

Why the last `2` is not getting removed?

Comment: 1) Don’t edit a list which is being iterated.  It leads to unexpected behaviour.  2) Create a new list of values which are not the target value; thus essentially ‘removing’ the element(s).

Comment: Add a `print(i)` inside the `for` loop before the `if`. You'll see it skips out on the second `2`, then the last call to `.remove(2)` will remove that second `2`, leaving out the last `2`.

Comment: See [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python) for the reason why, then see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/2745495) how to properly do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use `while in` method like this:

```
array = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]

def removeElement(value, array):
    while int(value) in array:
        array.remove(int(value))
    return array

print(delete_value(2, array))
```

The reason your code doesn't work is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058889/cannot-remove-the-last-element-of-a-python-list), and basically you shouldn't edit the same array that you use as input **and** use iterations

It works because we say to it that we want to delete the *value*, not the index `2` with replacing the usual square brackets `[]` with round brackets `()` in `array.remove(int(value))`.

Comment: yes, this was tested, test it urself, it works, i was confused as much as you was when i found out that you can remove values and not indexes